# Create new label column based on dictionary key value mapping in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a dictionary `d={1: [0.01, 0.02], 2:[1, 2], 3:[10, 20]}` and column in a data frame that contains all values in `d` e.g., `df['x'] = [0.01, 0.02, 1, 2, 10, 20]`, I'm looking to create a new column in my data frame that maps each value in col `x` to it's corresponding key according to dictionary `d`. The output is a creation of a new column, `df['x_label'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. I'm currently doing this brute force which is taking a lot of time. Is there a simpler optimized solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping dict by inverting the key-val pairs then use map to substitute the values

```
df['x_label'] = df['x'].map({i: k for k, v in d.items() for i in v})
```

---

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Unique but the best solution :-) However take care about floating point match. You can have some surprise.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be very careful when mapping real numbers to each other due to floating point error:

```
>>> 0.01 == 0.010000000000000001
True

>>> 0.01 == 0.01000000000000001
False
```

You can use `np.isclose`:

```
arr = np.array([(k, i) for k, v in d.items() for i in v])
msk = np.isclose(df['x'].values[..., None] - arr[:, 1], 0)
df['x_label'] = pd.Series(arr[:, 0], dtype=int)[np.nonzero(out)[1]]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       x  x_label
0   0.01        1
1   0.02        1
2   1.00        2
3   2.00        2
4  10.00        3
5  20.00        3

>>> msk
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])

>>> arr
array([[1.e+00, 1.e-02],   # 1, 0.01
       [1.e+00, 2.e-02],   # 1, 0.02
       [2.e+00, 1.e+00],   # 2, 1
       [2.e+00, 2.e+00],   # 2, 2
       [3.e+00, 1.e+01],   # 3, 10
       [3.e+00, 2.e+01]])  # 3, 20
```